# Hibernate: Entity field lazy set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am wondering if it is possible to lazy-set field of an entity. Consider this piece of code:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID")
    private Bar bar'
}



@Component
public class FooAssembler{
       @Autowired
       private BarRepository barRepository;

       public Foo toFoo(Long barId){
          return new Foo(barRepository.getOne(barId))
       }
}
```

Behind the scenes, we have an entity named Bar and BarRepository. Now I don't want to fetch Bar from its repo. I want to use only my barId argument and do not trouble my database with another fetch. Is this even doable?

Comment: If you don't want to fetch it at all, then create a constructor of `Bar` which takes the ID and sets it internally. then you can do `return new Foo(new Bar(barId));` which sounds like what you want. If you don't want the extra constructor, then just create a new `Bar` instance and set the ID to it

Comment: Please add fetch type annotation that you can only fetch parent record

`ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - isn't this going to be a problem during more sophisticated save operations (I mean cascade save)?

Comment: @Deedar Ali Brohi - I added it, but nothing changed (Bar is still fetched from repo)

Comment: Shouldn't pose a problem. You can test it and report back if you run into any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
@Component
public class FooAssembler{
       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager em;

       public Foo toFoo(Long barId){
          return new Foo(em.getReference(Bar.class, barId))
       }
}
```

Thanks to an EntityManager I am able to create a proxy (like Hibernate does) which I can use instead of fetching real entity.